# Schematic failures on ng serve

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, angular-cli

Recently I started running ng serve again on my project, and suddenly I am getting schematic errors.  It builds fine.

This is the serve target for my app:

```
    "serve": {
      "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:server",
      "options": {
        "customWebpackConfig": {
          "path": "./extra-webpack.config.js",
          "mergeStrategies": { "module.rules": "prepend" },
          "replaceDuplicatePlugins": true
        },
        "browserTarget": "evidentia4:build"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "browserTarget": "evidentia4:build:production"
        }
      }
    }
```

It hasn't changed in over a year.  But now I get:

```
Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(browserTarget).
```

I moved the browserTarget within the customWebpackConfig block, and now I get

```
 Data path "" should have required property 'main'.
```

Obviously something has changed, but I don't know what.   I have been updating angular and I am now on version:

```
Angular CLI: 8.3.0
Node: 12.7.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 8.2.3
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... platform-server, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.801.3
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.801.3
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.801.3
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.801.3
@angular-devkit/core              8.1.3
@angular-devkit/schematics        8.3.0
@angular/cdk                      8.1.3
@angular/cli                      8.3.0
@angular/flex-layout              8.0.0-beta.26
@angular/material                 8.1.3
@ngtools/webpack                  8.1.3
@schematics/angular               8.3.0
@schematics/update                0.803.0
rxjs                              6.5.2
typescript                        3.4.5
webpack                           4.39.2
```

I am flying blind since the angular.json was generated.

Any idea where to look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

```
"builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:server"
```

should have been

```
"builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server"
```

Answer (score 0):

The `angular.json` is being validated against `@angular\cli\lib\config\schema.json` file and the errors you have are related to this validation. I'd advise you to check if your `angular.json` complies with the schema. Also, the `ng update` command helps automatically migrate the code (`angular.json` included) so you could give it a try.

Comment: yes but it validate before too (before what?) and no problems. I pointed out the the angualr.json was generated. I think ng update actually created the issue